# Harry Potter fanfic where he is abandoned during the search for Horcrux for Ron and Hermione

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

In the fanfic it is related how Ron was in conflict with Harry and Hermione just like in the movie and how he forced Hermione to choose him or Harry.
In the one where she follows Ron, this haunts Harry, causing him to release his inheritance from his family (if I remember correctly it's from the Peverells).

The servant of this goes to look for him and help him in the state he was in.
This servant takes him to the family island that has a symbiotic relationship with his heir in which the status of the heir improves or worsens his ecosystem on the island.

On the island live some tribes of different species under the control of the family, but the only one of the lineages is Harry's. Later in the story, it is said that Ron joins the Death Eaters and how Voldemort seeks to expand how he attacks a Muggle town and how Hermione abandons Ron. While Harry on his inherited island creates an empire and goes making allies in the shadows without Voldemort realizing that he is coming.

The fanfic is long and has 2 parts and many chapters. The last time I read it was in FanFiction with a translator.

You can discard this in Spanish I already looked for it in Spanish during one of my searches. I am using a translator to translate what I have written previously.

Another fact that I can remember is that the 2 parts that exceeded 100k, were so long. The date is a little difficult, by 2010 or 2014 (and definitely in 2010) it had enough content.

Comment: So you're aware you need two new lines for a paragraph break. One doesn't work.

Comment: Dices que se puede descartar la posibilidad de que la historia esté en español porque ya has hecho una búsqueda, pero también es posible que no tuvieras éxito aunque estuviera en español. You say that we can discard the possibility that the story is in Spanish since you already looked for it, but it's possible that you didn't find it even though it was in Spanish.

Comment: I did an exhaustive search in Spanish in fanfiction other of my searches have also been in Indonesian to be able to discard it too. hice una búsqueda exhaustiva en español en fanfiction otras de mis busquedas han sido tambien en indonesio para poder descartarlo tambien.